# Finding max/min entry in arraylist element

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, increment

My program allows the user to repeatedly enter match results until the user enters 'stop', then the results are displayed. I just need to find the highest input value in my 'stats[2]' arraylist, which is the 'hometeam score'. So if the user enter 3 inputs, "Manchester City : Manchester United : 2 : 1 ... 
Chelsea : Arsenal : 0 : 1 ... 
Everton : Liverpool : 1 : 1" then it should display the number '2' as it's the highest value in that array. if that makes sense? I've set up the line at the bottom where I need it to be displayed.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String[]> stats = new ArrayList<>(); // initialize a container
                                                    // to hold all the stats
    System.out.println("please enter match results:");

    int matchesPlayed = 0;
    int invalidEntry = 0;

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String[] results = input.split("\\s*:\\s*");

        if (results.length == 4) {
            stats.add(results);
            matchesPlayed++;
        }

        else if (input.equals("stop")) {
            break;
        }

    } // end of while

    for (int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++) {

        if (stats.get(i)[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out
                    .println("no home team name entered on the following line:");
            invalidEntry++;
            matchesPlayed--;
        }

        else if (stats.get(i)[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out
                    .println("no away team name entered on the following line:");
            invalidEntry++;
            matchesPlayed--;
        }

        else if (stats.get(i)[2].trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no home score entered on this line");
            invalidEntry++;
            matchesPlayed--;

        }

        else if (stats.get(i)[3].trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no away score entered on this line");
            invalidEntry++;
            matchesPlayed--;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(stats.get(i)[0]) + " ["
                    + Integer.valueOf(stats.get(i)[2]) + "] " + " | "
                    + (String.valueOf(stats.get(i)[1])

                    + " [" + Integer.valueOf(stats.get(i)[3]) + "] "));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing with any invalid input
        }

    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Totals");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("total number of matches: " + matchesPlayed);
    System.out.println("total number of invalid entries: " + invalidEntry);
    System.out.println("highest home score: ");
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question besides "does that make sense". What's your question?

Comment: My question is how do I find the highest number entered in the [2] element of my arraylist and store it in an int so I can display it at the bottom?

Comment: Your "question" looks like a cookbook to do it. Why not doing it as you describe? Or is the question how to compare int values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through it, set a variable equal to the first element, and in the loop if there is an element that is higher than the variable currently is, change the variable's value to that. Then print the variable at the end

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how that would look in code? sorry I'm new to java

Comment: Thankyou very much!